# How do I say $x \in S \iff f(x) \in S$ in words?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

The phrase "$S$ is closed under $f$" means that $x \in S \implies f(x) \in S$. I'm looking for a phrase that means $x \in S \iff f(x) \in S$.

"Closed under $f$ and $f^{-1}$" isn't good enough because $f$ could not have an inverse and I would also like to be able to use it for "$x \in S \land y \in S \iff f(x, y) \in S$".

Comment: "$f$ preserves $S$ and its complement" maybe?

Comment: In ergodic theory, the phrase $T$-invariant subset refers to a set $U$ such that $T^{-1}[U]=U$, which is equivalent to your condition. However, in linear algebra, a $T$-invariant subspace is apparently one such that $T[U]\subseteq U$. So, while there is a word to express this, I'm hesistant to give it as an answer since it's not totally standard.

Comment: Why not just "x is in S if and only if f of x is in S"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom because if you look at wikipedia that is equivalent to mine ...

Comment: I guess you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

$x \in S \implies f(x) \in S$ means that $f(S) \subseteq S$ which implies that $S \subseteq f^{-1}(S)$, since generally, $f(A) \subseteq B$ implies $A \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$.

$f(x) \in S \implies x \in S$ means that $f^{-1}(S) \subseteq S$, since generally, $f(x) \in B \implies x \in A$ means that $f^{-1}(B) \subset A$.

Thus, $x \in S \iff f(x) \in S$ means that $S = f^{-1}(S)$.

Therefore I suggest: "$S$ is its own preimage under $f$".